# Any difference between Linux and Windows ping?

Tags: windows, linux

I tested a network issue and I just started using Linux on my netbook (works great!).
It seems that there shouldn't be any difference in sending ICMP packets, but I want to be sure about this.

Is there any significant difference between Linux and Windows ping (except the default packet size)?

Answer (score 8):

There should be little difference at the network layer. They do behave differently. The Linux ping does not terminate by default. You have to interrupt it (Ctrl-C) to end it and get a summary report.

The Linux ping also has many more diagnostic features.

Comment: Ping for windows: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true   Ping for Linux: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm

Comment: At least on Windows XP, the sequence number field was incorrectly written in host byte order rather than in network byte order, so the sequence numbers looked funny when viewed by a program that displayed them in network byte order.

Comment: @garyjohn: Ah, *that* must be why Wireshark displays it in both orders at the same time :/